# Is Dart's Optional operator an enum, similar to Swift's?

Tags: swift, dart

I want to know what the difference is between Dart Optional class Dart ?. operator and Swift optionals. I understand that they all help avoid null references and that Dart has the Optional.dart class which seems to operate similarly to the ?.

Swift Optional is just an enum that BASICALLY (I'm stressing basically) determines if it is null(empty)or not. How does Dart's optional differ from Swift's? Can they be used similarly? In Dart what is the difference between Optional class and using the ?. operator?
[Dart Classes](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#classes)
[Swift Optionals](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/swift-optionals-78dafaa53f3)
[Dart Optional Class](https://pub.dev/packages/optional#-example-tab-)

Dart:

```
void main() {
    NewClass nc = NewClass();
    nc.p = 3;
    print(nc.p); //prints 3
    nc = null;
    if(nc?.num != null) {
        nc.num = 4; //never entered
    }
    print(nc.num); // Uncaught exception:Cannot read property 
                   // 'get$num' of null
}

class NewClass {
    var p;
    int num;
}
```

Comment: This seems so broad. You seem to have the gist of it, what's your question?

Comment: @Alexander I updated the question for clarity. Thanks for bearing with me. I'm still trying to get the art of asking a SO question down. My question is: Is Dart's Optional an enum like Swift's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart does not have an `Optional` class that's part of the language.  The package that you linked to is a third-party package.

Dart has *null-aware operators* (such as `??`, `??=`, `?.`, `...?`).  They work specifically for `null` values; there are no special types involved.

Swift has optional *types*; it lets you declare that the type of a variable is `Int?`, which means it might be null or it might be an `Int`.

In Dart, *any* variable can store a null pointer.  Note that there is [ongoing work to add non-nullable types to Dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/110), so this should eventually change.